# indicator-sound should be a synonym of sound-menu

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I did some clean up in VLC today and noticed that these should be synonymed, unfortunately no one I can find in chat has enough rep to vote on the tag:

[indicator-sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/indicator-sound) <- [sound-menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sound-menu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, just  approved it and merged the tags.